# Fluent API and Method-Chaining Style Usage

Tags: c#, coding-style, method-chaining, fluent-interface

When programming against a fluent API or just using method-chaining, I've seen the style mostly like this:

```
var obj = objectFactory.CreateObject()
    .SetObjectParameter(paramName, value)
    .SetObjectParameter(paramName, value)
    .DoSomeTransformation();
```

What is the reasoning behind putting the dot at the beginning of the line instead of the end of the line like this:

```
var obj = objectFactory.CreateObject().
    SetObjectParameter(paramName, value).
    SetObjectParameter(paramName, value).
    DoSomeTransformation();
```

Or, is it merely a style thing that a team makes a consensus on?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's merely a style thing.

The advantage of putting the . at the beginning of the line is that it makes it more clear on a quick glance that this isn't a standalone method call.

For example, if you do:

```
var obj = objectFactory.CreateObject()
    .SetObjectParameter(paramName, value)
```

You can tell that `SetObjectParameter(...)` is a method being called on some other object, just looking at that line.  Doing this:

```
var obj = objectFactory.CreateObject().
    SetObjectParameter(paramName, value)
```

Requires you to look at the previous line to tell.  For example, this could be a formatting problem, ie:

```
var obj = objectFactory.CreateObject();
    SetObjectParameter(paramName, value);
```

(Here, `SetObjectParameter` would be a method on the current type, not on the type returned by `CreateObject()` - but, by looking at the second line, this is not apparent without the . beginning that line).

Comment: This rule doesn't just apply to Fluent interfaces, but more broadly to **all** method-chain statements, Fluent or otherwise.

Comment: Yes - (and that's part of why I never actually mention "fluent" in my answer ;) )

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've editing my question accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Three reasons I can think of:

- It's more obvious that each statement is a continuation of the previous one.
- I find that Visual Studio's intellisense prefers it this way.
- It's easier on the eye, at least in my opinion.

Comment: +1 for intellisense. IMHO this is the main reason for this convention. Methods are suggested when you write a dot. So if you want the method on a new line, the dot needs to be on this line also.